# Flutter - When I close the app and open it again, it doesn't work

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-hive

I have created an application to know the prices of products by reading the barcode. Prices are downloaded and stored in a hifi box. The app reloads the data every 6 hours.

The problem is that, after two or more days, when you close the application and open it again, a white screen appears, then a black screen, then the application closes and does not open unless the data is deleted.

I use:

```
get: ^4.6.5
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  async_button_builder: ^2.3.0+1
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_barcode_listener: ^0.1.3
  lottie: ^1.4.2
  http: ^0.13.5
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

I've tried deleting the data when closing the app, but I can't find a way to tell if the app is closed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine app life cycle with **WidgetsBindingObserver**. How to do it is:
Wrap your widget with WidgetsBindingObserver like

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver
```

then in your **initState**, add this:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
```

and inside your class:

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

under **detached**, you can program what to do when app is closing. But there are some bugs. It may only work when you close the app with back button or programatically.